# Cómo usar round con random entre 2 números en Python

Tags: python, random

Tengo un random entre números float y deseo que solo arrojen 2 decimales

```
random.uniform(50, 550)
```

que sean por ejemplo: 52.45, 430.23, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré esta solución:

```
round(random.uniform(50, 550), 2)
```

Comment: Fijate cómo en la otra respuesta se explica cómo funciona el código. Esta... Es solo código. Lee [answer] y pulsá en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta. Además, [aceptá](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta más útil.

Comment: Me alegra que encontraras una solución pero, como indica otro usuario, para que la respuesta sea de mayor ayuda a otras personas, deberías añadir una pequeña descripción con lo que hace o cómo soluciona el problema. Lee [answer] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa es calcular el valor como entero (previamente escalado) y dividir el resultado.

Si quieres tener dos decimales, usa un rango multiplicado por 100 y divide el resultado por 100.

```
random.randint(5000, 55000) / 100
```

Te evitas la llamada a `round()` y probablemente sea más rápido operando con enteros.